# NSButton over QTCaptureView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbutton

Is there any way to put NSButton object over QTCaptureView? 
I have done following,

1. In interface builder, added a
   QTCaptureView,
2. Added a button
   on top of QTCaptureView and it's
   allowing to do so.

When i launch the application, I can see the button over the QTCaptureView but when I start the Camera which will show the Preview in the QTCaptureView session, button is overriding by QTCaptureView.

Any idea what i am doing wrong ?

Basically I need to implement a Control which shows QTCaptureView and a Button over it; when user presses the button then I need to Launch the NSImageView over the QTCaptureView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable layers (-setWantsLayer:YES or turn it on in Interface Builder) on the view containing your capture view.